# Multiple dropdown menu filter in html

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, filter

Assume I have two dropdown Menu, is it possible to filter menu b by using HTML code only?
If not, which method can be apply for this case with simply code.

menu a with A B

menu b with A1 A2 B1 B2

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the help of Javascript.

Suppose you have one dropdown with some values as "Colours, Shapes, Names" with html as:

**Dropdown1:**

```
<select id="ddl">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Colours">Colours</option>
<option value="Shapes">Shapes</option>
<option value="Names">Names</option>
</select>
```

And you want to filter another one based on first dropdown selected value

**Dropdown2:**

```
<select id="ddl2">
</select>
```

**Then Apply below Javascript code:**

**Filter out:**

```
function configureDropDownLists(ddl1,ddl2) {
        var colours = new Array('Black', 'White', 'Blue');
        var shapes = new Array('Square', 'Circle', 'Triangle');
        var names = new Array('John', 'David', 'Sarah');

        switch (ddl1.value) {
            case 'Colours':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < colours.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, colours[i], colours[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'Shapes':
                ddl2.options.length = 0; 
            for (i = 0; i < shapes.length; i++) {
                createOption(ddl2, shapes[i], shapes[i]);
                }
                break;
            case 'Names':
                ddl2.options.length = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    createOption(ddl2, names[i], names[i]);
                }
                break;
            default:
                ddl2.options.length = 0;                
        }

    }
```

**And create option runtime for second dropdown:**

```
function createOption(selBox, text, value) {
        var opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = value;
        opt.text = text;
        selBox.options.add(opt);
    }
```

**Apply**:

`onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))"` in first dropdown, as:

```
<select id="ddl" onchange="configureDropDownLists(this,document.getElementById('ddl2'))">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="Colours">Colours</option>
<option value="Shapes">Shapes</option>
<option value="Names">Names</option>
</select>
```

So dropdown 2 gets filter based on first selected value.

Please refer to **[fiddle for live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e6hzj8gx/4/)**

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: @Hei Noah, are you fine with the explanation?

Comment: Your code is excellent on desktop computer but not working on mobile device. Do you have any advice?